# How do I tell database_cleaner to not run in the middle of a particular group of rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, database-cleaner

I have a set of ordered tests that mimick user actions and depend one on another.

How do I configure `database_cleaner` to not clean the database in the middle of these ordered tests?

```
/spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Sample of tests:

```
RSpec.describe Conversation, type: :model, order: :defined do
  context 'by default' do
    before :context do
      @alice = create :user
      @bob = create :user
      @subject = 'subject'
      @body = 'body'
      @conversation = @alice.send_message(@bob, @subject, @body)
    end

    it 'should have the subject it was opened with' do
      expect(@conversation.subject).to eq @subject
    end

    it 'should have one message upon opening' do
      expect(@conversation.messages.count).to eq 1
    end

    it 'should be initiated by @alice' do
      expect(@conversation.initiator).to eq @alice
    end

    it 'should be received by @bob' do
      expect(@conversation.recipient).to eq @bob
    end

    it 'should have two messages when bob sends a new message' do
      @conversation.add_message(@bob, 'This is my second message')
      expect(@conversation.messages.count).to eq 2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. My tests run in random, except these ones, they have the `order: :defined` tag. So I added an `unless` condition to the `config.before` statement in `support/database_cleaner.rb`.

It now looks like this:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```